# Current template's modify date

Tags: coldfusion

On my application.cfc file, I would like to have set a variable:

```
 application.gsversion = "Version 0.1.#year(x)#.#month(x)#.#day(x)#";
```

where x has the application.cfc's current modified date.

Comment: As per the answer below, the function is year(), not getyear().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add something like this to your onApplicationStart() method in Application.cfc:

```
var objAppFile = fileopen(expandpath('./Application.cfc'), 'read');
application.gsversion = "Version 0.1.#year(objAppFile.lastmodified)#.#month(objAppFile.lastmodified)#.#day(objAppFile.lastmodified)#";
fileclose(objAppFile);
```